# How to find CDF under presence of multiple random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, density-function, cumulative-distribution-functions

I am trying to derive CDF of the random variable $Y$ from the below expression.

$P_Y = \text{Pr}\bigl(Y\cdot k_1 < \frac{u_1}{X}+u_1k_2\bigr)$ ---(1)

where $\text{Pr}$ denotes probability, $X,Y$ are Nakagami-$m$ random variables, $k_1,k_2,u_1$ are constants.

My query is that, I am not getting how to find CDF of random variable $Y$ in equation (1) due to presence of random var $X$ .

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.